# Parser filas columnas tabla html

Tags: php, html

Tengo que programar un parser para guardar en la bd las columnas y filas de una tabla html, este es mi codigo:

```
$url = "https://xxxxxxxx";

        $html = file_get_contents($url);
        $html = fix($html);

        $fileName = fileSave("bienes", $html);

        $file = fopen($fileName, "r");

        $htmlTable = "";
        $switch = 0;
        $tipo = 0;

        while (($line_detail = fgets($file)) !== false) {
             .....
             .....
             // Aqui necesito recorrer las columas TD por fila TR para guardarlas en otro archivo, cómo puedo hacer eso más fácil ? 
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo que capturas el html, lo guardas en un archivo local, lo iteras y supongo que ahi viene la tabla con los tr y td.

Una forma sencilla de hacer lo que quieres es:

Extraes el codigo de la tabla:

```
        $htmlTable = "";
        $switch = 0;
        $tipo = 0;

        while (($line_detail = fgets($file)) !== false) {


            $pos = strpos($line_detail, '<table');

            if ($pos !== FALSE) {
                /* Bien o Lote */
                $switch = 1;                                
            }

            if ($switch == 1) {
                $htmlTable .= $line_detail;
            }

            $pos = strpos($line_detail, '/table');
            if ($pos !== FALSE) {
                $switch = 0;                                
            }

        }

        $htmlTable = "<html>" . $htmlTable . "</html>";
```

Luego, iteras las filas TR y las TD

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($htmlTable);
$rows = $dom->getElementsByTagName("tr");

$dataCols = "";
$identificador = "";

for ($i = 0; $i < $rows->length; $i++) {

    /* Solo los indices a procesar para el detalle de la subasta */
    /*if (!in_array($i, $detailRows)) {
        continue;
    }*/

    $cols = $rows->item($i)->getElementsbyTagName("td");
    for ($j=0; $j<$cols->length; $j++) {
         /* Aqui trabajas la logica segun lo que necesites ... */
    }
```

Finalmente trabajas la lógica que necesitas.

Solucionar completamente lo que necesitas con la información que das es complicado. Espero que esto te sirva de guía.

Saludos,